# Consistently Push Data From Server to Client Using SignalR

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I am working on a web application where i have some charts and i want to consistently get data from the database for the charts so that the user will always have the latest picture of the data. I used signalR and on the page load of Report page i am calling a server method in hub's class which is getting chart data from database and passing it onto the client and in turn a handler at client processes the data and draws the chart. What i want is to keep getting the data consistently. What are my options for it?

What is the best way to keep calling hub's method after a fix interval of say one minute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not poll on client or server. Instead use a service bus and publish your changes on that bus when they occur.

You can then forward these events to the client using SignalR. I have made a library for just that called SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki

I wrote a blog post about it here
http://andersmalmgren.com/2014/05/27/client-server-event-aggregation-with-signalr/

You can also look at the demo 
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/tree/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Demo.MVC4

Or look at the live demo here
http://malmgrens.org/signalr/

Comment: Data is in database. If this is his source of data he will need to "poll" against the database, unless the database he is using provides some kind of push mechanism what could be used to publish changes on that bus. However, data should be pushed to the client and should not be polled by the client

Comment: My guess is he have some kind of service that is updating the database? I would push the state change on a service bus after updating database. Its a much more solid solution than polling the database

Comment: @Anders I don't have control over the database. I just fetch data from it and display it.

Comment: OK, in that case you need to poll it. If your doing it from the Web application make sure you are doing it from a ASP.NET BackgroundWorker not a standard thread. Compare state between polls, if a change has occurred publish a change event. Use my library to forward that to the clients

Comment: Isn't that a little oversized. I like your EventAggreagtorProxy, but why not just calling the hub to send data to all clients after he has collected the data from database. This is just two lines of code without refrencing an additional library.

Comment: Abstraction mainly, plus reusability, it wont be one event for very long. Thats the reason why I made the lib, in my last project in the end before I abstracted it to this lib we had several hubs with similar or duplicated code

Answer (score 4):

SignalR makes polling the server obsolete. What you want to do is to schedule your database access. If you want to update your charts every minute, create a timer job in the server app where you collect data from database which has been added within the last minute. Then send this data to your clients. On this way your connected clients are always up to date without polling the server.

Comment: Polling on server is little better than polling on client